# Detect application crash based on app user's name

Tags: powershell, crash, user

been trying to create script to detect user's application crash. (Assume the computer is used by multiple users)

so far only managed to come out below code to query the application (based on user name) only but not app crash

```
gwmi -query "select * from win32_process where name='calc.exe'" | %{if($_.GetOwner().User -eq 'myUser'){
    #do something when app crash
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just check if gwmi returns anything.

```
if (gwmi -Query "select * from win32_process where name='calc.exe'" | where {$_.GetOwner().User -eq 'myUser'}) {
    write "app working"
}
else {
    write "app not working"
}
```